# FBX SDK how to retrieve user defined object properties

Tags: c++, 3dsmax, fbx

3DS MAX offers user-defined field for a node where arbitrary text can be put.

[image]

How can I retrieve this text using FBX SDK? I couldn't find any answer in the documentaion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FBX ASCII representation helped a lot.
User Defined property is stored in "UDP3DSMAX" FBX property.

Code:

```
FbxProperty p = m_node->FindProperty("UDP3DSMAX");

if (p.IsValid())
    FbxString str = p.Get<FbxString>();
```

Comment: What is 's' in `s.Get<FbxString>();` ?

Comment: It's 'p'. Fixed. Thanks for your attention