# Is is possible to iterate over the FbxProperties of an object that are not 'built in'

Tags: c++, autodesk, fbx

In FbxObjects Properties can be built in (such as [LclTranslation](http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_fbx_node.html#a1cd158556eedf934d3ac08095bf2fb4a) on an [FbxNode](http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_fbx_node.html#a1cd158556eedf934d3ac08095bf2fb4a)) or be dynamically added.

I am aware of [GetDstPropertyCount()](http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_fbx_object.html#aedf1805429315ca435cce6060ed69b24) & [GetDstProperty(int pIndex=0)](http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_fbx_object.html#a757fe6f91c0e127c03f5855f5c320799) but I believe this also returns the 'built in' properties too.

Is it possible to take an `FbxObject` iterate over only the `FbxProperty`s that are not 'built in'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can see example from documentation:
http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref__import_scene_2_display_user_properties_8cxx_example_html

Also you can use method `FindProperty` as mentioned here:
[FBX SDK how to retrieve user defined object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124397/fbx-sdk-how-to-retrieve-user-defined-object-properties/18124913#18124913)

Comment: Thanks. but the example you linked uses [GetFirstProperty](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/FBX-Developer-Help/cpp_ref/class_fbx_object.html#a29de8e90544c8c17c85c5b260c1ef93a) & [GetNextProperty](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/FBX-Developer-Help/cpp_ref/class_fbx_object.html#a245043a35065672de780dd6cd3eb2728) and the spec does not say that those dont include the 'built in' properties (just like `GetDstPropertyCount` & `GetDstProperty` which I linked in the question)

Comment: @Baggers, this example has a check `if (lProperty.GetFlag(FbxPropertyFlags::eUserDefined))`, so you can filter user properties.

Comment: :facepalm: how could I miss that? thanks so much for straightening that out for me.